# Charset after back button

Tags: php, get, character-encoding, smarty, back

I have search function that take info from $_GET['query'].

When I use direct link it's ok, something like:

[image]

BUT, when I click on some search result, and then press BACK BUTTON IN BROWSER, I have :

[image]

And I need to reload page, then it's fine. How can I fix it? I have no idea, I have

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in head.

Thinking about reload the page, using document.referrer, but it's empty after back button.

Using Smarty template engine, if it matters.

Comment: you need to send ajax request instead . like that you page shouldn't be refreched .

Comment: What you means? After refresh the page all is ok.